# I am getting a type error for this Python program I had to do for a class. I want to understand the issue

Tags: python, typeerror

I am getting an error
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper.

The program below is supposed to check for files in the 2 directory path listed and if both files exist print the content of them, if they don't exist it prints "Unable to access one or more files".
It will print the content of the first loop but then give me the above error and not print the second. I can't seem to figure out whats wrong. I put the file paths to variables and the .txt files as well

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import os.path

path_E = Path('E:/CPT180Stuff')
os.chdir(path_E)

dogPath = (path_E / 'pets' / 'dogs')
catPath = (path_E / 'pets' / 'cats')
cat_files = (catPath / 'catnames.txt')
dog_files = (dogPath / 'dognames.txt')


if os.path.isfile(cat_files and dog_files):
    os.chdir(path_E)

        #prints contents of dognames file
    for filename in os.listdir(dogPath):
        dog_files = open(dog_files, 'r')
        pupFile = dog_files.read()
        print(pupFile)
        dog_files.close()


        #prints contents of catnames files
    for filename in os.listdir(catPath):
        cat_files = open(cat_files, 'r')
        kittenFile = cat_files.read()
        print(kittenFile)
        cat_files.close()

        #opens catnames file to append end and add names.
    catnames = open('catnames.txt', 'a')
    catnames.write('Princess\nFreya\n')
    catnames.close()
    catnames = open('catnames.txt')
    kittenFile = catnames.read()
    catnames.close()
    print(kittenFile)

else:
    print('"Unable to access one or more files."')
```

the main issue is occurring here:

```
for filename in os.listdir(dogPath):
    dog_files = open(dog_files, 'r')
    pupFile = dog_files.read()
    print(pupFile)
    dog_files.close()


    #prints contents of catnames files
for filename in os.listdir(catPath):
    cat_files = open(cat_files, 'r')
    kittenFile = cat_files.read()
    print(kittenFile)
    cat_files.close()
```

This assignment is already been graded but the instructor never got back to me on explaining this error or how I can fix it.

Comment: What is your traceback call? Could you please show it?

Comment: `os.path.isfile(cat_files and dog_files)` does not do what you think it does. It should be `os.path.isfile(cat_files) and os.path.isfile(dog_files)`

Comment: You don't need those loops at all.  You're fetching the name of every file in the "dogs" directory, but you don't use those names.  You read the single file in "dog_files".  And the first time through the loop, you overwrite the "dog_files" name with the file object, so if there were two files in that directory, it would explode on the second one, because you're trying to pass a file object as a file name string.  If you're just reading two files, you don't need loops.

Comment: My traceback call is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gorri\Desktop\College Work\CPT180_ShellScripting\Assignments\Programs\workWithFiles2.py", line 24, in <module>
    dog_files = open(dog_files, 'r')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper